# Como eliminar elementos da lista através de uma condição?

Tags: r

Utilizei a seguinte função:

```
splitfile<-split(training,list(training$group1,training$city))
```

e isso me retorna uma lista de dataframes com linhas diferentes, com base nas variáveis que selecionei.

No entanto, é retornado um dataframe com 0 linhas, pois não há correspondência de uma categoria de uma variável com a categoria de outra variável.

Meu objetivo é eliminar este dataframe que contém 0 linhas da lista.

Mas, *preciso fazer isso por **condição***, pois, podem existir casos que me retornem vários dataframes com 0 linhas e, não seria eficiente eliminar um por um.

`dput` para auxílio na resposta:

```
training=structure(list(bin = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1), modalidade = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("unik", "opfin", 
"compras"), class = "factor"), group1 = c(1, 2, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 
1, 2, 1), missing = c(NA, 4, 5, NA, 7, 6, NA, NA, 4, 5), score1 = c(3, 
2, 4, 4, 7, 6, 4, 3, 6, 7), valor = c(100, 200, 321, 34, 3424, 
2344, 4232, 43, 22, 22), gender = c("M", "M", "M", "M", "M", 
"F", "F", "F", "F", "F"), via = structure(c(2L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("1via", "2via"), class = "factor"), 
income = c(1605.52545357496, 1957.10460608825, 3463.77286640927, 
2241.49697413668, 2575.95523679629, 3004.28174249828, 3458.30937661231, 
1786.68619645759, 2065.093211364, 1561.55416276306), city = c("San Francisco", 
"Santa Monica", "Santa Monica", "Santa Monica", "Santa Monica", 
"Hollywood", "Hollywood", "Hollywood", "Hollywood", "Hollywood"
), CPF = c(38676865809, 43245353454, 34565456765, 38676865809, 
38676865809, 44322211189, 44322211189, 12345678900, 12345678900, 
33444455590), desbloq = structure(c(10553, 9537, 10553, 10553, 
9212, 10658, 10957, 11822, 11822, 10188), class = "Date"), 
trans = structure(c(10556, 9541, 10555, 10554, 9218, 10660, 
10958, 11823, 11826, 10190), class = "Date")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), .Names = c("bin", "modalidade", "group1", "missing", "score1", 
"valor", "gender", "via", "income", "city", "CPF", "desbloq", 
"trans"), class = "data.frame")
```

Se a resposta incluir algum pacote que faça isso de forma elegante, melhor ainda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não é assim tão difícil quanto isso eliminar todos os dataframes com zero linhas de uma só vez. É até muito mais fácil que possa parecer, basta uma instrução.

Explicado por partes.

Primeiro, vou usar o `sapply` e não o `lapply` porque o segundo tem uma lista como saída, enquanto que o `sapply` é a mesma função com `simplify = TRUE`.
E o `NROW` porque também functiona com objetos sem um atributo dimensão.

```
sapply(splitfile, NROW)
#    1.Hollywood     2.Hollywood 1.San Francisco 2.San Francisco 
#              3               2               1               0 
# 1.Santa Monica  2.Santa Monica 
#              1               3
```

Em segundo lugar, é só transformar estes resultados em índice lógico:

```
sapply(splitfile, NROW) != 0
#    1.Hollywood     2.Hollywood 1.San Francisco 2.San Francisco 
#           TRUE            TRUE            TRUE           FALSE 
# 1.Santa Monica  2.Santa Monica 
#           TRUE            TRUE
```

E usar esse índice para ficar com o que se quer.

```
result <- splitfile[sapply(splitfile, NROW) != 0]
```